# Save and restore position X Y of HTML elements in a DB with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to make a floor planner like page for tables of a Restaurant. Every square of the page represent a table and they are draggable.

```
  <div  id="drag-1" class="draggable">
    <p> Table 1 </p>
  </div>
  <div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> Table 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div id="drag-3" class="draggable">
    <p> Table 3 </p>
  </div>
```

After dragging they have new coordinates changed appling a *transform: translate()* made by the js function.

The question is how I can save the coordinates in a MySQL DB with PHP and restore the position of every square after refreshing page?

Here is complete code to see it working

https://jsfiddle.net/1sfx4ubn/

Comment: Collect data-x and y on button press, and send that data to a .php file (using AJAX) and save in db.

Comment: Can you give me an input how to do that? And after how I can reload their position?? @geertjanknapen

Comment: I'm not able to write your code for you, however I feel like I gave you a great pointer so why don't you go ahead and try